# Read or unread message status with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a messaging system on my site where users can send messages to one another, I have a mysql database with the following columns in it :

```
 id sentto sentby msgbody created
```

"sentto" is the person to whom msg is sent.
"sentby" is the msg sender.

I use select statement to display msg on page.

Now i want to add status function Read|unread to my msging system, so that if foo sends a msg to bar ,bar opens his inbox and reads the msg, then foo will see status Read in outbox for the msg.

How is this possible?

Do I need to create 2 more columns "read" "unread" in my chat table?

Any idea?

Comment: maintain a single column for read/unread status...if someone sent a message make it unread and if message is read make it read

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column `hasread, tiniyint (1), default as 0` after `sentby`.
When the receiver (bar) opens the message update the db record `hasread` = 1.